# The mechanic behind the variable capture

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I am learning JavaScript and currently learning about scopes and closures. I stumbled upon the following example in Wikipedia regarding accidental variable capture :

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
// Incorrect: e is bound to the function containing the 'for' loop, not the closure of "handle"
for (var e of elements) { 
  e.onclick = function handle() { 
    alert(e.id);
  } 
}
```

I understand what a variable capture is, I just can't see how it's happening here, if anyone could explain what is happening with the contexts/environments here I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It's a key difference between `let` and `var` for creating variables.

Comment: The scope of variables declared with `var` is the entire function. So all the iterations share the same `e` variable, and the closure will get the last value.